# How to upload base64 image resource with dropzone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload generated client side documents (images for the moment) with [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/).

```
// .../init.js

var myDropzone = new Dropzone("form.dropzone", {
    autoProcessQueue: true
});
```

Once the client have finished his job, he just have to click a save button which call the save function :

```
// .../save.js

function save(myDocument) {

    var file = { 
        name: 'Test',
        src: myDocument,
    };

    console.log(myDocument);

    myDropzone.addFile(file);
}
```

The console.log() correctly return me the content of my document

```
 data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...
```

At this point, we can see the progress bar uploading the document in the drop zone but the upload failed.

Here is my (standart dropzone) HTML form :

```
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="dropzone">
    <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div>
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I got a Symfony2 controller who receive the post request.

```
// Get request
$request = $this->get('request'); 

// Get files
$files = $request->files;

// Upload
$do = $service->upload($files);
```

Uploading from the dropzone (by drag and drop or click) is working and the uploads are successfull but using the myDropzone.addFile() function return me an empty object in my controller :

```
var_dump($files);
```

return

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag)#11 (1) {
  ["parameters":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I think i don't setup correctly my var file in the save function.
I tryied to create JS image (var img = new Image() ...) but without any success.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Take a look at this bundle: https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle. It solves the problem you are having and many other you will probably have in the future.

Comment: Sorry but no it don't. My dropzone is fonctionnal as my controller and action. It is the use of the addFile function which is not working because i work with an input containing the image source (creating dynamically in js) and i don't know how to transform it to be accepted by the addFile fonction.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally i found a working solution without creating canvas :

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    'use strict'
    var byteString, 
        mimestring 

    if(dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') !== -1 ) {
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1])
    } else {
        byteString = decodeURI(dataURI.split(',')[1])
    }

    mimestring = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    var content = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        content[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)
    }

    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(content)], {type: mimestring});
}
```

And the save function :

```
function save(dataURI) {

    var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURI);
    myDropzone.addFile(blob);

}
```

The file appears correctly in dropzone and is successfully uploaded.
I still have to work on the filename (my document is named "blob").

The dataURItoBlob function have been found here : [Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata)

**[EDIT]** : I finally wrote the function in dropzone to do this job. You can check it here : https://github.com/CasperArGh/dropzone
And you can use it like this :

```
var dataURI = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAmAAAAKwCAYAAA...';
myDropzone.addBlob(dataURI, 'test.png');
```

Comment: simply adding `blob.name='quirks';` before `addFile(blob);` worked for me to add a file name. thx

Comment: You should propose a PR on the official repository for you `addBlob` method.

Comment: You can also use filer.js for datauri to blob: https://github.com/ebidel/filer.js/blob/master/src/filer.js#L137

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment currently and wanted to send this to you.

I know you found your answer, but I had some trouble using your Git code and reshaped it a little for my needs, but I am about 100% positive this will work for EVERY possible need to add a file or a blob or anything and be able to apply a name to it.

```
Dropzone.prototype.addFileName = function(file, name) {
    file.name = name;
  file.upload = {
    progress: 0,
    total: file.size,
    bytesSent: 0
  };
  this.files.push(file);
  file.status = Dropzone.ADDED;
  this.emit("addedfile", file);
  this._enqueueThumbnail(file);
  return this.accept(file, (function(_this) {
    return function(error) {
      if (error) {
        file.accepted = false;
        _this._errorProcessing([file], error);
      } else {
        file.accepted = true;
        if (_this.options.autoQueue) {
          _this.enqueueFile(file);
        }
      }
      return _this._updateMaxFilesReachedClass();
    };
  })(this));
};
```

If this is added to dropzone.js (I did just below the line with `Dropzone.prototype.addFile = function(file) {` potentially line `1110`.

Works like a charm and used just the same as any other. `myDropzone.addFileName(file,name)`!

Hopefully someone finds this useful and doesn't need to recreate it!

Comment: before anyone asks I have pasted blobs into it from screenshots (currently only on IE), but have not attempted to use it to upload other types of files.

Answer (score 0):

1) You say that: "Once the client have finished his job, he just have to click a save button which call the save function:"

This implies that you set `autoProcessQueue: false` and intercept the button click, to execute the saveFile() function.

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
    // let the event not bubble up
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // process the uploads
    myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

2) check form action

Check that your form `action="/upload"` is routed correctly to your SF controller & action.

3) Example Code

You may find a full example over at the official **[Wiki](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone)**

4) Ok, thanks to your comments, i understood the question better:

**"How can i save my base64 image resource with dropzone?"**

**You need to embedd the image content as value**

```
// base64 data
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

// insert the data into the form
document.getElementById('image').value = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
//or jQ: $('#img').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));

// trigger submit of the form
document.forms["form1"].submit();
```

- You might run into trouble doing this and might need to set the "origin-clean" flag to "true". see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#security-with-canvas-elements
- [how to save html5 canvas to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135664/how-to-save-html5-canvas-to-server)

Comment: Thanks you for your response.

1)

2)

Comment: 1) autoProcessQueue is currently "true". I have a unique dropzone which allow the user to drag and drop / click to upload but also an editor to create new images. I need autoProcessQueue to be "true" : creating a new image should push the created file into the queue which is immediatly uploaded if there is no more job.

Comment: 2) As I said : Uploading from the dropzone (by drag and drop or click) is working and the uploads are successfull, so my route / controller / action are correctly configured . Only using the javascript function myDropzone.addFile() return me an empty object in my controller.

Comment: 3) This example doesn't help me :). My main problem is what kind of object should I pass to the addFile() function as I have a string as image source

Comment: addFile() accepts filenames https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/master/lib/dropzone.js#L805 What you have is a image resource string.

Comment: Is there a way to create a js object with my ressource string that dropzone can use ?

Comment: Please see #4 in my comment. Use the base64 string and insert it in a hidden or image element in the DOM, then send the content. Its possibly easier with a pure AJAX send, then trying to push this into Dropzone.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try to do like that. By the way, i find an issue asking for this behaviour : https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/468

Comment: I changed the question title to be more explicit. Thank you very much for your help.