# dropzone js use $.Ajax and not inbuilt functions

Tags: dropzone.js

I am planning to use dropzone and I am new to it, I am reading some documents

I am planning to use dropzone for the UI and uploading into server, using some other API's, so how do I tell dropzone to use my custom method and pass the success or failure to the UI

I found some other interesting posts like this[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178092/uploading-blob-arraybuffer-with-dropzone-js/39215551)

Comment: In the options init function I am doing this, 
            this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
                debugger;
                saveFiletoServer(file, 'account'); //Custom method
            });
        so the file is saving as needed, but how do I tell Dropzone the file is successful, it is throwing an error in UI.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the [init()](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-init) function and wait for the response:

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
    init: function () {
        this.on("complete", function (data) {
             var res = JSON.parse(data.xhr.responseText); 
             //use the request's statusCode anyway you want to
             if(data.xhr.status === 200)
             {
                //modify the UI
             }
        });
    }
    dictResponseError: "error message when failed"
};
```

[HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)